# Why does the solution of this equation $y'' = x^2y$ have asymptotic behavior for $y \sim x^n e^{\pm x^2/2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

When I deduced the Schrodinger equation of the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator according to this article [One-dimensional Schr¨odinger
equation](http://www.fisica.uniud.it/%7Egiannozz/Corsi/MQ/LectureNotes/mq-cap1.pdf), The original formula 1.7：
$$
\dfrac{d^2 \psi}{d\zeta^2} = (\zeta^2 - 2 \epsilon ) \psi(\zeta) \tag{1.7}
$$
The original text says "One can easily verify that for large ξ (such that ε can be neglected) the solutions
of Eq.(1.7) must have an asymptotic behavior like"
$$
\psi(\zeta) \sim \zeta^n e^{\pm \zeta^2/2} \tag{1.8}
$$
I don't understand why its solution has such asymptotic behavior?

Comment: as $\zeta \rightarrow \infty$ , $\epsilon$ becomes neglible. does this help?

Comment: @asgeige I know this, so my title is $y'' = x^2 y$, I'm clearly ignoring $\epsilon$.

Comment: The idea is that $y(x)=x^n e^{\pm x^2/2}$ satisfies an equation of the kind $$y''=x^2y(1+o(1))$$ This is the kind of rigor I have come across in Physics courses.

Comment: Are you wondering why it's asymptotic at all, or wondering why it's asymptotic to this expression in particular? It's been a while since I did Difeqs, but it's clear from the $x^2$ term that the solution will increase rapidly. Whence the actual expression, that would require me to remember solving these.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do is to solve the complete differential equation in terms of the parabolic cylinder $D$ functions
$$\psi=c_1\, D_{\frac{1}{2} (2 e-1)}\left(\sqrt{2} \zeta\right)+c_2\,D_{\frac{1}{2} (-2 e-1)}\left(i \sqrt{2} \zeta\right)$$ and expand as a series   around $\epsilon=0$.

$$\psi=\sqrt[4]{2}\, c_2 \,e^{\frac{\zeta^2}{2}}\, H_{-\frac{1}{2}}(i \zeta)+\sqrt[4]{2}\, c_1\, e^{-\frac{\zeta^2}{2}}\, H_{-\frac{1}{2}}(\zeta)+O(\epsilon)$$ where appear Hermite polynomials.